# Automatically selecting features for anomaly detection using gaussian distribution

Tags: machine-learning, pca, gaussian, anomaly-detection

For certain data, we may need to manually create features which are combinations of earlier features to get a better algorithm. The below distribution (and any other where the distribution is an ellipse with it's axis NOT aligned to the feature axes) are easy examples of gaussian distribution not working.

*The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r88Ei.png) is from Stanford's Machine Learning course on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/).*

It was told in that course that a multivariate gaussian distribution works the best for it OR we can develop a new feature x_3 = x_2 - x_1 and x_4 = x_2 + x_1, and use these two new features as the axes for the ellipse, since with these axes the ellipse will no longer be *tilted* and normal gaussian distribution can work.

I want to automate this new feature selection and was thinking that using PCA (with a high variance %) would help in creating a new features that are of 'linear type', like x_2 - x_1. Kind of how the long diagonal black line from this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzDIT.png) (*from the same course as above*) is exactly what we need, and this black line was generated using PCA.

Would the above work? Is there something better than we can do to automate generating new features (of linear type and otherwise)? Neural networks and Kernels were something that I also thought of but I have a hunch that they would be very expensive computational wise.

Answer (score 0):

The family of the problems you're looking for is called [dimensionality reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction). Yes, PCA is the default approach to such problems, fully analogous to how linear regression is the default approach to regression.

It won't, however, find a feature of the form x_2 / x_1, because that is a nonlinear transformation. The features it will find will be of the form  a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 (in the mean-centered coordinates). There are many methods that allow you to look for such features automatically. Kernel PCA that you mentioned is one such method, although, like all kernel methods, it does not explicitly search for features and only selects the most useful ones from a predefined set. Among the methods that can search infinite classes of nonlinear features my personal favorite is [genetic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming). It mostly focuses on regression, but it should be straightforward to apply it to dimensionality reduction. Note that it is not something that will work out of the box and will require some trial and error. If you do decide to take that route, here are some useful resources: [3](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2739480.2754693) and [4](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Methods that search large classes of nonlinearities are inherently computationally costly. If performance is critical, study the system that generates the distribution, identify a class of nonlinearities that might be useful and use something like kernel PCA for feature selection. Or have an approach like the one described in [3](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2739480.2754693) extract useful features from the data in one slow, but automatic study, then freeze the feature search and let the linear selector that's sitting on top of it make decisions for each particular measurement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have edited my original question to better convey what I was trying to ask (x_2 - x_1 rather than x_2 / x_1). I am currently a newbie at machine learning, with just one course under my belt hence your genetic programming resource is great for future reference but it'll just go over my head currently.

Comment: For features like x_2 - x_1 just linear PCA should work.